# Nginx Rewrite subdomain url to top level domain

Tags: nginx

I need to be able to redirect the following subdomain URL to top level domain as in:

bie.husky.com/login ----> bie.husky.com

I have the following piece of code in my nginx config that does not seem to eliminate the '/login' part when redirecting...

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name bie.husky.com;

   set $my_var 0;
   if ($host = 'bie.husky.com/login') {
   set $my_var 1;
}

     if ($my_var = 1) {
     rewrite ^ http://bie.husky.com redirect;
}


  location / {
    root   /var/www/bie;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's best to avoid `if` *if* possible :). See: [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). Try using a location instead. You might also want to read: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bie.husky.com;
    root    /var/www/bie;
    index   index.html index.htm;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;

    location = /login {
        return 302 $scheme://$host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fun problem.